# Cypress - can't click on span

Tags: reactjs, cypress

In my React.js code I have the following:

```
        <span 
            onClick={addToList} 
            className='ms-2 pt-2' 
            title='Adding a new row.'
            data-testid='t-editableListItem-add'>
            <BsFilePlus size={25} role='button' />
        </span>
```

In unit test the `span` can be clicked on:

```
await userEvent.click(screen.getByTestId('t-editableListItem-add'));
```

However in Cypress (13.6.4) I can't do the same:

```
    cy.findByTestId('t-editableListItem-add').click();
```

or

```
    cy.findByTestId('t-editableListItem-add').findByRole('button').click();
```

neither of them works.

I've even tried the `realClick()` from https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events but it didn't help.

Any idea please what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What error do you get when running either of the Cypress commands? Is it possible you need to click the child with `role='button'`, instead of the parent `<span>`?

Comment: No error Cypress but the function attached to `onClick` of span is just not executed. I tried to click on the `span` and on the icon under it which has the button role but no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `userEvent.click(...)` is working for you in unit tests, you can also import it into Cypress tests and use it there.

You just need to provide it with the DOM element, which can be obtained from the Cypress query via the yielded jQuery object.

```js
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event'
// also requires install of @testing-library/dom

it('clicks a button using userEvent', () => {

  cy.get('[data-testid="t-editableListItem-add"]')
    .then($span => {
      const element = $span[0]
      userEvent.click(element)
    })
})
```

---

#### Missing event listener

If that does not work, the problem could be that the event handler is not attached at the time your Cypress test attempts to click.

See [When Can The Test Click](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/when-can-the-test-click/) for a full rundown of this problem.

The test can wait for the event listener using the [hasEventListeners command](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-cdp?tab=readme-ov-file#haseventlisteners) that comes with the `cypress-cdp` package.

```js
it('clicks a button using userEvent', () => {

  // wait for the event listener to be attached
  cy.hasEventListeners('[data-testid="t-editableListItem-add"]', { type: 'click' })

  cy.get('[data-testid="t-editableListItem-add"]').click()
})
```

Comment: Oh gosh, apologies, I should have waited for one more day with this question. It was my fault, there was a small error in my code which made `click()` Cypress function look like not working. Your answer helped a little bit to find my bug so I am happy to accept it.